# How to skip over whitespaces in .map. Ruby

Tags: ruby

This is my code:

```
def weirdcase (string)
  string.chars.map.with_index { |letter, index|
    unless index.odd?;
      letter = letter.upcase
    else
      letter
    end }.compact.join("")
end
```

This is what it's supposed to do:

```
"ThIs Is A TeSt"
```

And this is what I got:

```
"ThIs iS A TeSt"
```

It's giving me the wrong string in return because it's counting/including the white spaces in my
code. All I need to do is find a way to skip the white spaces then I'm good to go.
Thanks!

Comment: Skipping whitespace would result in `"ThIs Is A tEsT"` (note the last word). It seems like you're supposed to change the case _per word_.

Comment: @Dev89 : IMO, this is more a question about the algorithm instead of Ruby programming. Using the `index` here is a bad idea, as you found out yourself.  Instead you would have to maintain your own `lettercount` index, which you increment only, when you encounter a letter, and you test this _lettercount_ for even/odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem**

I assume that the objective is to capitalize, for each word, all letters at even indices (the first letter of the word having index zero).

Here are two ways to do that. Both methods use [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a regular expression. Depending on requirements it may be necessary to change `str.gsub...` to `str.downcase.gsub...` for both methods.

**Use a regular expression to match one- or two-characters strings, two if possible, and capitalize those strings.**

```
def weirdcase(str)
  str.gsub(/(?<=\A| |[^ ]{2})[^ ]{1,2}/) { |s| s.capitalize } 
end
```

```
weirdcase "this is a sentence for    testing"
  #=> "ThIs Is A SeNtEnCe FoR    TeStInG"
```

The regular expression reads, "match one or two characters other than spaces, two if possible (`[^ ]{1,2}`), that are immediately preceded by one of the following: the beginning of the string (`\A`), a space or two characters other than spaces. `(?<=\A| |[^ ]{2})` is a *positive lookbehind*.

`s.capitalize` invokes the method [String#capitalize](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize) on the match.

**Use a cycling enumerator**

```
def weirdcase(str)
  enum = [:upcase, :downcase].cycle
  str.gsub(/./) do |s|
    if s == ' '
      enum.rewind
      ' '
    else
      s.public_send(enum.next)
    end
  end
end
```

```
weirdcase "this is a sentence for testing"
  #=> "ThIs Is A SeNtEnCe FoR TeStInG"
```

The regular expression `/./` matches each character in the string.

See [Array#cycle](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle), [Enumerator#rewind](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind), [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and [Object#public_send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send).

Note the following.

```
enum = [:upcase, :downcase].cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: [:upcase, :downcase]:cycle>
enum.next
  #=> :upcase
enum.next
  #=> :downcase
enum.next
  #=> :upcase                       
enum.rewind
  #=> #<Enumerator: [:upcase, :downcase]:cycle>
enum.next
  #=> :upcase
enum.next
  #=> :downcase
... ad infinitum
```

Comment: hi, what's the difference between `\p{L}+` and `\w+`

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks! I missed the point that \w would include the digits as well. thank you.